# $\epsilon$ nets of Compact Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $K$ be a metric space. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. We say that $E \subset  K$ is an $\epsilon$-net of $K$ if for each $x \in K$ there exists $e \in E$ such that $d(x,e) < \epsilon $ (i.e. any element of $K$ may be approximated within $\epsilon$ by an element of $E$). We
say that a set $C \subset K$ is $\epsilon$-separated if for any two points $x, y \in C$,
$x \neq y, d(x, y) \geq \epsilon$.

Let $K$ be compact. Denote by $N(K,\epsilon)$ the size (number of elements)
of the smallest $\epsilon$ net of $K$ and by $M(K,\epsilon)$ the size of the largest
$\epsilon$-separated set. Prove the following relation
$M(K,2\epsilon) \leq  N(K,\epsilon) \leq  M(K,\epsilon)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we have a $\varepsilon$-net of $n$ elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and let $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ be $2\varepsilon$ separated. Since $K\subseteq \bigcup B(x_i,\varepsilon)$, each $a_i$ is in some ball. That is, to each $a_i$ we can associate some $x_{\sigma i}$ such that $a_i\subseteq B(x_{\sigma i},\varepsilon)$. But since the $a_i$ are separated, $\sigma$ must be an injection. Thus $m\leqslant n$. This means that $M(K,2\varepsilon)\leqslant N(K,\varepsilon)$.